# How do I put a file path (to a harddisk folder) into a js variable, without getting "Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a set of files on my harddisk using javascript.

But it does not like my file path:

```
 var fileUrl = "E:\Dropbox\ThaiHome\Github\pattayanightWeb\src\templates\toplist\";
```

I get the following error:

```
var fileUrl = "E:\Dropbox\ThaiHome\Github\pattayanightWeb\src\templates\toplist\";
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your problem is the backslashes. The backslash is an escape character, in JavaScript strings. It's used to specify special characters: \t for tabs, \n for newlines, \" if you want to embed a " in your string.

Your string contains \D, \T, \G, etc. And it's these that it's not recognizing.

To include a backslash in a string you need to escape it: \\.

```
var fileUrl = "E:\\Dropbox\\ThaiHome\\Github\\pattayanightWeb\\src\\templates\\toplist\\";
```

Comment: That did the trick - way smarter than..  " + String.fromCharCode(47) + "  :D

Answer (score 1):

`\` in JavaScript is an escape character, you need two of them like this `\\` to present the character `\`.